# Rails - Clean way of calling model method in respond_to differently depending on the format

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, dry

I have some code like this:

```
respond_to do |format|
 format.html { @all_activities = current_user.recent_activities(@size_per_page,params[:start],nil) }
 format.csv { @all_activities = current_user.recent_activities(nil,params[:start],nil); build_activity_csv }
 format.xls { @all_activities = current_user.recent_activities(nil,params[:start],nil); 
   send_data(build_excel_all, :filename => "#{Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}_Activity_All.xls", :type => "application/xls", :disposition => 'attachment')
   }
   format.js { @all_activities = current_user.recent_activities(@size_per_page,params[:start],nil) }
   format.pdf { @all_activities = current_user.recent_activities(nil,params[:start],nil); prawnto :filename => "#{Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}_Activity_All", :inline => false 
}
end
```

As you see, I am calling the same method in the different formats, but in some cases I use the **@size_per_page** variable, and sometimes I call the method with **nil** instead.

Anyone recommend a better, cleaner or non repeating way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: You may also want to post this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd separate that call into a function but that's just me.

Here's how I would do it:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { set_all_activities(@size_per_page) }
  format.js { set_all_activities(@size_per_page) }
  format.csv do
    set_all_activities(nil)
    build_activity_csv
  end
  format.xls do 
    set_all_activities(nil)
    send_data(
      build_excel_all, 
      :filename    => "#{Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}_Activity_All.xls",
      :type        => "application/xls",
      :disposition => 'attachment')
  end
  format.pdf do 
    set_all_activities(nil)
    prawnto(
      :filename => "#{Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}_Activity_All",
      :inline   => false)
  end
end


def set_all_activities(size)
  @all_activities = current_user.recent_activities(size, params[:start], nil)
end
```

I'm assuming `params[:start]` and the last `nil` argument are consistent, right?

Comment: I like it. Much cleaner. And yes, those two are consistent :-)